# How to place two section elements next to each other using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to implement the following HTML structure using HTML5 and CSS. The `section` elements have to be next to each other. The right `section` element must have a `margin-left` of 30 px and a fixed `width` of 220 px.

[image]

What I have so far is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<section id="section-left">My left section</section>
<section id="section-right">My right section</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#section-left {
   float: left;
}

#section-right {
   float: right;
   width: 220px;
   margin-left: 30px
}
```

My problem is that the left `section` does not fill the remaining space up to the right `section` element. My result looks as follows:

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: They have to be floated to the same direction.

Comment: You say "The left section element must have a margin-left of 30 px and a fixed width of 220 px." but in your CSS its the right section with a width.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the right section. That was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the order of your sections and use this CSS:

```
#section-left {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#section-right {
    width:220px;
    margin-left:30px;
    float:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z5Rga/1/)**

Comment: Can this be done without switching the order of the sections? That would very useful if you want the right section to go below the left section, using a media query that removes the float for smaller screen sizes.